# How to read a multidimensional String Array from a plist in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array

I'm using the following code to save a 2D String array to a plist:

```
func saveFavourites(favouriteStops: [[String]]) {
    let directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)

    if let library = directories.first {
        if let libraryUrl = URL(string: library) {
            let favouritesUrl = libraryUrl.appendingPathComponent("favourites.plist")

            // Write favourites to disk
            let favsArray = favouriteStops as NSArray
            print(favsArray)
            favsArray.write(toFile: favouritesUrl.path, atomically: true)
        }
    }
}
```

The above snippet properly creates the .plist file (confirmed by looking at the simulator's filesystem in `~/Library/Developer/CoreServices`). However, when I try reading it back to a `NSArray` with the following snippet, it results in `nil`:

```
let directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)

    if let library = directories.first {
        if let libraryUrl = URL(string: library) {
            let favouritesUrl = libraryUrl.appendingPathComponent("favourites.plist")

            // favsToLoad is nil
            let favsToLoad = NSArray(contentsOf: favouritesUrl)

            // Do stuff with favsToLoad, if it would load properly

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing two very basic things wrong.

- First, *never* make a URL from a file path by saying `URL(string)`; this is a *file on disk*, so you must use `URL.fileURL`.
- Second, don't start with a file path at all! Obtain the directory as a URL right from the start.
- (Also, though I do not know whether this is the source of the issue, do not read and write directly in the Library directory. Use the Documents directory, the Application Support directory, or similar.)

So, for example, I would write:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let docsurl = try fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let favouritesurl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("favourites.plist")
```

Comment: good catch on the use of `URL(string:)`. I missed that part. That's likely the cause, although it's curious that the OP says he can see a new file added in the filesystem.

Comment: @DuncanC Yeah, that puzzles me too. But that's actually why I added the bit about not reading and writing directly in the library directory. :)

Comment: The second bit (that you should use URL-based methods rather than path-based methods) is good advice but not a requirement. Using the older path-based methods is discouraged, but they do still work.

Comment: @DuncanC Sure, agreed. But my point is, you're going to need a URL so why bother starting with a string path and converting, especially since he's converting _wrong_?

Comment: Isn't the library directory returned by `url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)` on a device the library directory in your app sandbox, and isn't it writeable?

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem. You misspelled "favorites". :)

But seriously...

Plists can only contain a very small set of "property list objects": (dictionaries, arrays, strings, numbers (integer and float), dates, binary data, and Boolean values).

If your array's "object graph" (the objects the array contains and any container objects inside the array recursively contain) contain anything other than the above types, the save will fail.

I don't honestly know what gets saved when it fails. Have you tried opening the plist file in a text editor and looking at it?

My guess is that something other than a string has snuck into your array, it's not one of the above types, and THAT'S why it's failing.

Comment: Yeah, good, I was going to add that. I'm betting the plist he's writing is empty.